# Very slow lexicographic ordering in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-performance

I've got a `vote_pairs` view which looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vote_pairs AS
    SELECT
        v1.name as name1,
        v2.name as name2,
        ...
    FROM votes AS v1
    JOIN votes AS v2
        ON v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id;
```

And, with ~100k rows in the `votes` table, queries across this view take about 3 seconds to execute.

However, when I add an additional filter on the names:

```
… ON v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id AND v1.name < v2.name;
```

The runtime quadruples, taking almost 12 seconds for queries across `vote_pairs` to complete.

This runtime is consistent regardless of the position of the limit… For example, the query is equally slow if the filter is moved to the `WHERE` clause of the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM vote_pairs WHERE name1 < name2;
```

What's going on? Are lexicographic comparisons slow in Postgres? Is this something else? And how could I improve the speed of this query?

Vote table:

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
    topic_id INTEGER REFERENCES topics(id),
    name VARCHAR(64),
    vote VARCHAR(12)
)

CREATE INDEX votes_topic_name ON votes (topic_id, name);
CREATE INDEX votes_name ON votes (name);
```

The output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` without the name filter:

```
db=# CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vote_pairs AS
db-#     SELECT
db-#         v1.name as name1,
db-#         v2.name as name2
db-#     FROM votes AS v1
db-#     JOIN votes AS v2
db-#         ON v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id;
CREATE VIEW
db=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM vote_pairs;                                                                                                                                                                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=3956.38..71868.56 rows=5147800 width=28) (actual time=51.810..1236.673 rows=5082750 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on votes v1  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.019..18.358 rows=112950 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1882.50..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=50.671..50.671 rows=112950 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on votes v2  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.004..20.306 rows=112950 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 1495.963 ms
(6 rows)
```

And with the filter:

```
db=# CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vote_pairs AS
db-#     SELECT
db-#         v1.name as name1,
db-#         v2.name as name2
db-#     FROM votes AS v1
db-#     JOIN votes AS v2
db-#         ON v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id AND v1.name < v2.name;
CREATE VIEW
db=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM vote_pairs;
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=3956.38..84738.06 rows=1715933 width=28) (actual time=66.688..6900.478 rows=2484900 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id)
   Join Filter: ((v1.name)::text < (v2.name)::text)
   ->  Seq Scan on votes v1  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.023..24.539 rows=112950 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1882.50..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=65.603..65.603 rows=112950 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on votes v2  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.004..26.756 rows=112950 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 7048.740 ms
(7 rows)
```

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):

```
db=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM vote_pairs;
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=3956.38..71345.89 rows=5152008 width=28) (actual time=56.230..1204.522 rows=5082750 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id)
   Buffers: shared hit=129 read=1377 written=2, temp read=988 written=974
   ->  Seq Scan on votes v1  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.008..20.492 rows=112950 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=77 read=676
   ->  Hash  (cost=1882.50..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=55.742..55.742 rows=112950 loops=1)
         Buckets: 2048  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 752kB
         Buffers: shared hit=52 read=701 written=2, temp written=480
         ->  Seq Scan on votes v2  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.004..22.954 rows=112950 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=52 read=701 written=2
 Total runtime: 1499.302 ms
(11 rows)


db=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM vote_pairs WHERE name1 > name2;                                              
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=3956.38..84225.91 rows=1717336 width=28) (actual time=51.214..6422.592 rows=2484900 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id)
   Join Filter: ((v1.name)::text > (v2.name)::text)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2597850
   Buffers: shared hit=32 read=1477, temp read=988 written=974
   ->  Seq Scan on votes v1  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.008..22.605 rows=112950 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=27 read=726
   ->  Hash  (cost=1882.50..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=50.678..50.678 rows=112950 loops=1)
         Buckets: 2048  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 752kB
         Buffers: shared hit=2 read=751, temp written=480
         ->  Seq Scan on votes v2  (cost=0.00..1882.50 rows=112950 width=18) (actual time=0.005..21.337 rows=112950 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=2 read=751
 Total runtime: 6573.308 ms
(13 rows)
```

Miscellaneous notes:

- `VACCUM FULL` and `ANALYZE votes` have been run
- Both 8.4.11 and 9.2.3 behave in the same way

Comment: Can you provide the schema for the table, as well as the results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query>`?

Comment: Ok, added. Also, I lied a little bit about the times — turns out that some of that time was going to other queries. But the ratio here is still about the same 1.5 seconds versus 7 seconds.

Comment: I can't help thinking the structure of your base table is the root cause of the problem. First, it has no key. Second, there's no clear reason why it might make sense to join it to itself on topic_id. It seems like the result will just be a Cartesian product of names or of votes. [What's the real problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/161666)?

Comment: I wonder if there's something about the way the join with the filter is handled that requires more memory. Can you try bumping up `work_mem`? I know that's not really a solution, but if it helps, it might be a clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: By that do you mean the `votes` table? Well, yes — I could define the key `PRIMARY KEY (topic_id, name)`, but that wouldn't change anything in this case. And yes — the result is a cartesian product of names and votes, which I'm using as an intermediary step in calculating the relationship between voters (ex, do people A and B often vote together?) So in this case, yes — my real problem is that the filtering is super slow.

Comment: Could you run `VACUUM ANALYZE votes`, without `FULL`? And please, include output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) …`, it'll work in 9.* versions only though.

Comment: @TomAnderson When I set `working_mem = 100MB`, nothing seems to change.

Comment: @vyegorov ok, updated the question to include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` after running `VACUUM ANALYZE votes`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': the real problem seems to be a data modelling problem. `name` appears to be a hidden domain (should be a (integer)  FK to a persons table, and vote could be an int, or  even a boolean or enum)

Comment: @wildplasser yes, I could `CREATE TABLE persons (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(64))`… But that would complicate my use case (for various Good Reasons).

Comment: No, that would only make the rest of your life more comfortable. And there are always `VIEW`s to help you.

Comment: Worth taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, text comparisions are sometimes slow. You may want to try:

```
SELECT * FROM vote_pairs WHERE name1 > name2 collate "C";
```

This should be somewhat faster, because it doesn't take locale-specific comparision rules into account. Also, your explain analyze result suggests your shared_buffers may be set too low.

Comment: Woo! This did the trick — adding the `collate` brings the speed of the query-with-the-comparison up to the same (approximate) speed as the query without. Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should probably add a `CHECK` constraint on the `name` column that confines it to the 7-bit ASCII character range that's common to (almost - argh, Shift-JIS) encodings. If that's not acceptable to the app, then `C` collation probably isn't going to be either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In this case, though, this isn't a full-blown app… Just some one-off data analysis. But I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the slowness is added because the `v1.name < v2.name` filter adds some fixed set of operations for every row in the cross product join.

A more efficient operation would be to check `v1.name <> v2.name`, but then you would get duplicate results such as `(A,B), (B,A)`. *Then* we can add back the `v1.name < v2.name` into a `WHERE` clause which would prune the duplicates and hopefully hit a reduced number of rows due to our simplified filter.

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vote_pairs AS
    SELECT
        v1.name as name1,
        v2.name as name2
    FROM votes AS v1
    JOIN votes AS v2
        ON v1.topic_id = v2.topic_id AND v1.name <> v2.name
    WHERE v1.name < v2.name;
```

(Edit: Seems `COLLATE "C"` is the way to go, but I'll leave this answer because it's a nice trick for reducing row exposure to slow operations.)

Comment: Ok! This does help a bit — it reduces the runtime from ~7 seconds down to ~4 seconds… But that's still much slower than without the comparison.